# SYMFONY FORM alternative to createNamedBuilder() function (same stuff but outside the Controller)

Tags: forms, symfony-forms, symfony

I found the function createNamedBuilder() to change the name of a SYMFONY form.

It works fine to display the same FORM several times on a same page and not have any confusion between the different SUBMIT button referring to a same and single FORM name (which I was getting when using the createForm() function).

**My issue is to have that stuff hanging in the Controller, which means I have to repeat it each time I want to use it**. And I'd rather have it in my **MyFormClassType** under one of the function **buildForm()**  or **setDefaultOption()**, knowing that the **id** that I use to build my custom form name comes from the 'data' (the class linked as 'data_class' to **MyFormClassType**), I input when I create the form in the CONTROLLER.

To sum it up; I would like:

```
   $myFormClass = new MyFormClass($id);    
    createForm('MyBundle\Form\MyFormClassType',$myFormClass,array());
```

Instead of:

```
$myFormClass = new MyFormClass($id);
$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('form_name'.$myFormClass->id,'MyBundle\Form\MyFormClassType',$myFormClass,array())->getForm();
```

And have **'form_name'.$myFormClass->id** managed somewhere in  'MyBundle\Form\MyFormClassType'.

Any idea?